# How to show list of only hidden packages adb android?

Tags: android, adb

there's an adb command for showing all packages list which includes hidden packages also: `adb shell pm list packages -u`
But, I want to get list of only packages which are hidden in the android with `adb shell pm hide 'package.name'`

Comment: What do you mean with "hidden" packages?

Comment: you can hide app to show in android with adb shell pm hide 'package.name'

Answer (score 2):

Was looking for the same and didn't find a single command to do this. Unix diff does the job though

`diff <(adb shell pm list packages -u) <(adb shell pm list packages)`